# Does Bootcamp work for all users on a mac?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, user-account, 64-bit

I am in the process of installing Bootcamp to my Mac. A question has just crossed my mind

Can you only use windows from the account you set it up on, or does it work for all users on the mac?

For example, if I set up Bootcamp using Bootcamp Assitant on User X's account, can User Y use Bootcamp on the Mac without having to log in to user X's account?

Thanks.

Comment: You're booting into a completely different OS.  macOS doesn't come into play when you boot Windows other than it resides on another partition on the drive.

Answer (score 6):

The ability to boot into windows is not limited by what user installed it. That said everyone will need either their own Windows logon or have the windows password to the windows user you create.

The Windows users are totally unrelated to MacOS users.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you set a Firmware Key or a Bitlocker password on Windows, everyone can boot into Windows with **option (alt)** key, and login with their own account or a guest account. Windows is an OS that is completely seperate from macOS, and macOS has no control over Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any connection between your Mac and Windows. you can assume Boot Camp as a whole another PC. To set user privileges, you need to set that on Windows. And any user can boot into your Windows from Mac unless you set up accounts for them in Windows.